# Keyboard layout switch's wrong behavior

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I have two keyboard layouts. I use LShift+LAlt to switch them.

But first switch in any app's window causes layout switch in my desktop environment (Gnome Shell), but language remains the same. After that, layout indicator remains in "inverted" state: it shows wrong current layout. It can be repaired by manually changing layout in indicator's menu.

How can I get rid of this problem?
My system is Ubuntu 15.10. Desktop Environment is Gnome Shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1437411) in gnome-settings-daemon, first documented 2015-03-27.